# como leer un archivo de texto de una carpeta resources

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo una carpeta llamada resources que he añadido al directorio src en un proyecto java, que contiene un archivo de texto que tengo que leer. Lo he intentado con este metodo pero me da error en esta linea: `fr = new FileReader(archivo);`

```
public String leerArchivo(String ruta) {
            
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String linea = "";
    try {
        //archivo = new File(ruta);
        //archivo=new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(ruta).getFile());
        archivo=new File(getClass().getResource(ruta).getFile());
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        // Lectura del fichero
        /*while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(linea);
            
        }*/
        linea = br.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
        // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
        // una excepcion.
        try {
            if (null != fr) {
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return linea;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué ruta estás pasando este método? ¿Qué versión de java usas? Por favor adjunta esos detalles para reproducir tu error.

Comment: Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://onlinegdb.com/F2SIbBp5G) basado en tu código.

Comment: Hola, con el ejemplo funcional de Jaime Menendez me funciona bien. Pero cuando hago clean and built y lo ejecuto fuera del netbeans me da un error NullPointerException en esta linea: `String ruta = tiendaSuvenirs.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/modoRemotoOLocal.txt").getPath();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los archivos dentro del JAR no pueden ser leídos con File o Files, ni podrás hacer referencia a sus rutas con Path o Paths.

Para Java, los recursos dentro del JAR no se consideran archivos reales. Es decir, no podrás leerlos como un archivo normal del sistema. Para ello deberás utilizar un InputStream y a partir de ahí, trabajar con lo que te pueda proporcionar.

En el caso de InputStream, existe un método que te puede devolver todos los bytes leídos de ese recurso, (si es que existe).

---

Por ejemplo, para leer una fuente, existe el método Font.createFont, que le puedes pasar un File, en el caso que el archivo de tipografías este fuera del JAR, o le puedes pasar un InputStream para leerlo si esta dentro.

```
InputStream input = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fontPath);      
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, input);
```

Sin mas, si quieres leer un archivo dentro del JAR utiliza gRAS (getResourcesAsStream),
que te devuelve un InputStream.

En tu caso, para leer el archivo deberás utilizar el InputStream que te da getResourceAsStream. Lamentablemente no podrás utilizar las clases FileReader ni BufferedReader, ya que estas también piden al menos un File.

En su lugar, puedes obtener directamente el texto del archivo convirtiendo los bytes del InputStream en un String.

Observa el siguiente método:

```
/**
 * Devuelve el contenido de un recurso interno
 * dentro del JAR en forma de String.
 * 
 * @param source Nombre del recurso.
 * @return El contenido del recurso en un String.
 */
private static String getSourceString(String source) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String stringFromBytes = null;
    
    try {
        
        inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(source);
        
        if(inputStream == null)
            return null;
        
        byte[] bytesOfStream = inputStream.readAllBytes(); // leer los bytes del archivo de exportaciones.
        
        stringFromBytes = new String(bytesOfStream); // convertir los bytes a un string.
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeResources(inputStream);
    }
    
    return stringFromBytes;
}

private static void closeResources(Closeable stream) {
    if(stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close();     
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Eso devolverá un String con el texto del archivo.
Ahora si quieres leerlo linea a linea puedes utilizar el método lines() del String.

```
String fileText = getSourceString("com/proyecto/recursos/file.txt");

if(fileText == null) return;

Stream<String> lines = fileText.lines();
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Entonces a partir de ahí puedes realizar splits, o todas las verificaciones linea a linea que quieras.

La razón por la que en el IDE funciona, es porque cuando no se genera el JAR, son archivos reales, estas en tu computadora, específicamente en la carpeta que utiliza el IDE para el proyecto.

---

Hace tiempo tuve el mismo problema y este enlace me ayudo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371019/get-resource-file-from-jar-file

Recuerda que cuando utilices el InputStream, la ruta del recurso no debe iniciar con "/"
y tiene que comenzar con el nombre del paquete: "com/proyecto..." no "src/com/proyecto...".

En caso de que la clase utilizada en "Clase".class.getResourceAsStream, este en la misma ruta del recurso, puede simplemente llamar a "/file.txt" ya que se encuentra en el mismo paquete y la barra indica que empiece la búsqueda desde la mismo paquete.

Comment: Para la lectura me ha funcionado. Tambien necesito escribir en el pero no se si eso es posible.